# mysql loop and formatting results

Tags: php, mysql, css

i have this code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id ASC");
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    if ($i%2==0) {
        <div class="main">
            <div class="wrapper-main">
    }
       <article>test string1</article>
       <article>test string2</article>
if ($i++%2==1) {
            </div>
        </div>
    }  
}
```

This work perfect when the count of results are pair number but if are odd the "div" is not closed. how resolve?

My result must be:

```
 <div class="main">
     <div class="wrapper-main">
         <article>test string1</article>
         <article>test string2</article>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="main">
     <div class="wrapper-main">
         <article>test string1</article>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

Your second test evaluates the value of `$i` *before* it increments its value (you may want to google for "post increment"). Therefore you do not close your div's when `$i` is odd. You actually do close an inexistant div when `$i` is even!

Change your second test from

```
if ($i++%2==1)
```

to

```
if ($i++%2==0)
```

May I suggest my preference (for clarity) :

```
if ($i%2==0) {
    // close your divs
}
$i++;
```

Comment: Given the expected result, your code logic is wrong.
The `if` should surround `<article>test string2</article>` only. The condition itself is still wrong, though.

Comment: I have try your code but not work the last 2 div are not closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following AFTER the while loop:

```
if ($i%2==1) {
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Of course this is not valid PHP nor HTML code, I am only using your "syntax" to show my answer to your problem.